# ASP.NET 4 Webforms Bundle error in content pages

Tags: asp.net, webforms, bundle

here´s the deal. 
I´m using bundling in my webforms site and it works like a charm in the MASTER page. When I inspect the file in browser, it shows that all the js and css files were truly minified and bundled.

But when i do any other bundling, the return is the entire site inside the bundled file?

Something like this.

"<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles-css/master") %>"

"<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles-css/home") %>"

The first works perfectly and the second returns the whole HTML page inside of it.

I could not post the images of the code difference :( . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Dammit! The dumb thing was confusing my bundle name.

I changed from 
"<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles-css/home") %>"
to
"<%: Styles.Render("~/bundles-css/intern") %>"
and it worked! :/.

I believe that is was confusing with some of my aspx files. :/